# React is not rendering component and does not give errors as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As mentioned react does not give error nor renders component. It might be due to nested maps. How would you go about it?

my array is as follows:
["HS":{"shortDetails": {...}, "longDetails": {...}, "photos":[...]}, "HS2": {"shortDetails": {...}, "longDetails": {...}, "photos":[...]}, ... ]

**parent component**

```
const ListingCarousel = (props) => {

    return (
        <Carousel responsive={responsive} containerClass="carousel-container" itemClass="carousel-item-padding-40-px">

            {
            props.listingDetails.map((data, key) => {
              Object.keys(data).map((item, i) => {
                return <ListingCard 
                        key={i} 
                        src={data[item].photos[0].src} 
                        title={data[item].shortDetails.title} 
                        price={`${data[item].shortDetails.price.amount} ${data[item].shortDetails.price.recurringPayment}, ${data[item].shortDetails.price.priceType}`} 
                        address={`${data[item].shortDetails.address.street}, ${data[item].shortDetails.address.mun} ${data[item].shortDetails.address.ward}, ${data[item].shortDetails.address.district}, ${data[item].shortDetails.address.province}`}
                      />
                      
              })
            })
            }
    
        </Carousel>
    )
  }
```

**child component**

```
const ListingCard = (props) => {
console.log(props);
    return (
            <div key={props.key} class="card" style={{width: "380px", height:"300px"}}>
            <img class="card-img-top" src={props.src} class="img-fluid" style={{height:"200px", width:"380px", objectFit:"cover"}} />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{props.title}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">{props.price}</h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">{props.address}</h6>
            </div>
            </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your code [here](http://react.new/)?

Comment: Use this "return Object.keys(data).map((item, i) => {"

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ it gives an error:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Comment: Oh wait, so I had to from both inside and outside of the Objet.keys function. This worked. Thanks @FerhatBAŞ!